# Tensorflow error on Android

Tags: android, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am learning Tensorflow and following a tutorial I was able to make a custom model to run it in an Android App but I am having problems with it. I have the following code:

```
    public void testModel(Context ctx) {
        String model_file = "file:///android_asset/model_graph.pb";
        int[] result = new int[2];
        float[] input = new float[]{0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F};
        TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;
        inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(ctx.getAssets(), model_file);
        inferenceInterface.feed("input", input, 68);
        inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"output"});
        inferenceInterface.fetch("output", result);
        Log.v(TAG, Arrays.toString(result));
    }
```

I got an error when the app try to run the `inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"output"})` method:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: In[0] is not a matrix
[[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_input_0_0, W1)]]
```

I don't believe the model I created is the problem because I was able to use it in a Python code with positive result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message (`In[0] is not a matrix`), it appears that your model requires the input to be a matrix (i.e., a two dimensional tensor), while you are feeding a one dimensional tensor (vector) with 68 elements.

In particular, the `dims` argument to [`TensorFlowInferenceInterface.feed`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java#L291) seems incorrect in the line:

```
inferenceInterface.feed("input", input, 68);
```

Instead, it should be something like:

```
inferenceInterface.feed("input", input, 68, 1);
```

if your model expects a 68x1 matrix (or `34, 2` if it expects a 34x2 matrix, `17, 4` for a 17x4 matrix etc.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that the model was expecting a matrix not an array. I modified the model a op `tf.reshape`,that way I could set an input of an array and the model changes it to a matrix later